# Как получить данные с RecylerView Edittext

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-edittext, adapter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой Layout(Изображение) который мы получаем в RecyclerView, таких layout-ов можно создать несколько. Как я могу получить значение из каждого?

Вот код моего Адаптера:

```
private Context mContext;
private int flag;

public PackagesAdapter(Context context, int flag){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.flag = flag;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PackagesAdapter.PackagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.packages_layout, parent, false);
    PackagesAdapter.PackagesViewHolder packagesViewHolder = new PackagesAdapter.PackagesViewHolder(view);
    return  packagesViewHolder;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PackagesAdapter.PackagesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

    String packName = holder.name.getText().toString();
    String components = holder.components.getText().toString();
    double price;
    if (holder.price.getText().toString().equals(""))
        price = 0.00;
    else
        price = Double.parseDouble(holder.price.getText().toString());

    CreateEvent2 event = new CreateEvent2(packName, Global.packageDates, price, components);
    Global.moreEvents.add(event);

// В классе Global имеется List<String> moreEvents = new Arraylist<>();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return flag;
}

public class PackagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout bankAccount;
    private TextView id, currency, info;
    private EditText datePicker1, price, components, name; 


    public PackagesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageId);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageMoreName);
        datePicker1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageMoreDates);
        bankAccount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageBankAccount);
        currency = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageMoreCurrency);
        info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageTransactionInfo);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageMorePrice);
        components = itemView.findViewById(R.id.packageMoreComponents);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете назначение метода `onBindViewHolder`.
В нем надо получить данные из вашего списка и отобразить. Т.е. примерно так

```
holder.name.setText(moreEvents.get(position).getName());
```

А чтобы получить данные, которые пользователь введет в `EditText`, вам надо повесить на него слушатель и менять данные по позиции. Типа:

```
holder.price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
        double price = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        // Изменить одно поле
        // moreEvents.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).setPrice(price);

        // Или весь объект обновить
        Event2 event = moreEvents.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
        Event2 editedEvent = new Event2(event.getId(), ..., price,...);
        moreEvents.set(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition(), editedEvent);        
    }
    ...
}
```

ЗЫ `getItemCount` должен возвращать `moreEvents.size()`
ЗЗЫ Ваша проверка для цены недостаточная. Лучше преобразуйте к `double`, ловите исключение и обнуляйте.

Comment: Метод который вы написали getAbsoluteAdapterPosition, не работает(высвечивается красным)

Comment: это метод холдера. писал в окне ответа, считайте это псевдокодом.

Comment: вы вот тоже написали, что у вас moreEvents типа List<String>, а добавляете туда CreateEvent2 ...

Comment: CreateEvent2 модель которую я через Retrofit отправляю на сервер

Comment: При использовании метода который вы мне отправили когда я пытаюсь ввести текст в edittext выкидывает с ошибкой  index =0 length = 0

Comment: В ответе описана идея, тут нет никаких проверок. Вам придется сделать проверки самостоятельно и еще много чего.